# Parsing JSON array to individual variables in Azure logic apps

Tags: json, azure, salesforce, integration

I am trying to write a logic app to parse a Json Object and Update salesforce record. I am pretty new to both Salesforce and Azure logic apps, so I am trying to figure this out.  Below is my Json File

```
{
  "ContactId": null,
  "Email": "asong@uog.com",
  "IsInternalUpdate": false,
  "Preferences": [
    {
      "PrefCode": "EmailOptIn",
      "CurrentValue": "Yes",
      "Locale": "en-US"
    },
    {
      "PrefCode": "MobilePhone",
      "CurrentValue": "1234567890",
      "Locale": "en-US"
    },
    {
      "PrefCode": "SMSOptIn",
      "CurrentValue": "Yes",
      "Locale": "en-US"
    },
    {
      "PrefCode": "ProductTrends",
      "CurrentValue": "ProductTrends,OffersPromotions",
      "Locale": "en-US"
    },
  ]
}
```

Based on email value, I need to update a custom object in Salesforce. From the preference array, Prefcode value maps to a field in Salesforce and Current value maps to field value. i.e below snippet translates to set the value for EmailOptIn field in Salesforce to "Yes"

```
    {
      "PrefCode": "EmailOptIn",
      "CurrentValue": "Yes",
      "Locale": "en-US"
    }
```

So far, I was able to pass hardcoded values and successfully update salesforce record from logic app.

I am trying to set individual variables for each field, so that I can pass it directly to salesforce. I have two issues that I am running into

1. What is the best way to capture the field value mapping?
2. I have couple of fields that allow multi select, how do I set the multiselect values. Below is an example

```
{
      "PrefCode": "ProductTrends",
      "CurrentValue": "ProductTrends,OffersPromotions",
      "Locale": "en-US"
}
```

Below is my logic app structure

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g8RX.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyH98.png)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What is the best way to capture the field value mapping?

I could able to achieve your requirement by constructing JSON with required details and used parse JSON step again. Below is the flow of the logic app that worked for me.

[image]

[image]

> 2. I have couple of fields that allow multi select, how do I set the multiselect values. Below is an example

I have converted the `ProductTrends` into array and retrieved each item using its index as below.

```
array(split(body('Parse_JSON_2')?['ProductTrends'],','))[0]
```

```
array(split(body('Parse_JSON_2')?['ProductTrends'],','))[1]
```

Alternatively, if it is possible to make things work from the target end for multiple values, you can send in array or string directly to salesforce.

Below is the complete JSON of my logic app.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": {
                    "ContactId": null,
                    "Email": "asong@uog.com",
                    "IsInternalUpdate": false,
                    "Preferences": [
                        {
                            "CurrentValue": "Yes",
                            "Locale": "en-US",
                            "PrefCode": "EmailOptIn"
                        },
                        {
                            "CurrentValue": "1234567890",
                            "Locale": "en-US",
                            "PrefCode": "MobilePhone"
                        },
                        {
                            "CurrentValue": "Yes",
                            "Locale": "en-US",
                            "PrefCode": "SMSOptIn"
                        },
                        {
                            "CurrentValue": "ProductTrends,OffersPromotions",
                            "Locale": "en-US",
                            "PrefCode": "ProductTrends"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@array(split(body('Parse_JSON_2')?['ProductTrends'],','))[0]",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_string_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Preferences",
                            "value": "\"@{items('For_each')?['PrefCode']}\":\"@{items('For_each')?['CurrentValue']}\",\n"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['Preferences']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Preferences",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Compose')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "ContactId": {},
                            "Email": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "IsInternalUpdate": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "Preferences": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "CurrentValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "Locale": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "PrefCode": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "PrefCode",
                                        "CurrentValue",
                                        "Locale"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Parse_JSON_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@concat('{',slice(variables('Preferences'),0,lastIndexOf(variables('Preferences'),',')),'}')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "EmailOptIn": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "MobilePhone": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "ProductTrends": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "SMSOptIn": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

After following the above process, I could able to get the preferences values individually.

[image]